# How do we change styles in a word contentcontrol via VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, office-interop, word-contentcontrol

I'm trying, since a few days, to control a word document via *vb.net*. I've put some *contentControl* in it in order to mark the location where I have to make automatic changes.
Writting in it is really easy, replacing also.
Writting a continuous text with a lot of paragraphs is a little more tricky but I manage to do it via functions.
Where I have more problems is by writting one title in a "Style1", a subtitle in a "Style2" and the text in "Normal style".
When I write this :

```
With tfDocx.BodyCC("startFormulas").Range
    .Style = tfDocx.Doc.Styles("Titre 2")
    .Text = "Produits"
End With
```

I have the good text in the good style. But when I add this code:

```
With tfDocx.BodyCC("startFormulas").Range
     .Style = tfDocx.Doc.Styles("Titre 2")
     .Text = "Produits"
End With
With tfDocx.BodyCC("startFormulas").Range.Characters.Last
    .InsertParagraphAfter()
    .Style = tfDocx.Doc.Styles("Titre 3")
    .Text = "essais"
End With
```

The .InsertParagraphAfter is not taken into account and when I debug it I have a single line "Produits essais" in my word document with needer of the two styles.
Does someone have an idea?

Comment: any tips in VBA will help you? will you convert it into vb.net on your own?

Comment: Yes of cours VBA to VB.net is pretty the same in this kind of operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting your code to VBA (second part where you add 'essais' text) I would have this one:

```
With CC.Range.Characters.Last
    .InsertParagraphAfter
    .Move wdParagraph   '!!!!!!!!!
    .Style = "Nagłówek 1"
    .Text = "essais"
End With
```

As you can see I've added one line with `'!!!! comment` moving insertion point to next paragraph which was add with `.InsertParagraphAfter method`.

Comment: Nice it worked greatly but for the ones who are looking for the same thing in VB.net `.Move wdParagraph` is `.Move(word.wdUnits.wdParagraph)`
Thanks for your solution!